# Will a Canon 200D's STM lens make the same sound on a Canon 3000D/1500D?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-mount, sound, ef-s

What I understand is that STM is a part of lens, not camera. Canon 3000D or 1500D makes noise while focusing. So if we buy a Canon EF-S STM lens, which is used on 200D, will it be compatible and produce same amount (not precisely, just a general idea about it) of noise?

i.e., if Canon EF-S STM lens is used on 200D, it produces a noise (not irritating noise as compared to other old lenses) that can be heard at upto distance of 200 meters, will this produce same noise and would be heard at around same distance?

Comment: [STM vs Non STM lenses for still photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87088/75526)

Comment: Yes, if you replace a non-STM lens by an STM one on the same body, it should make less noise while focusing. However, if the focus noise is important for you, this must be while shooting video and this site is only for still photography.

Comment: @xenoid I _think_ this is asking if the same STM lens will make less noise on a different body.

Comment: @mattdm No. I mean would it make same amount of noise?

Comment: Wait, you *want* it to be audible?

Comment: No no. Suppose Canon EF-S STM lens is used on 200D, it produces a noise (not irritating noise as compared to other old lenses) that can be heard at upto distance of 200 meters, will this produce same noise and would be heard at around same distance? I don't want it to be audible. I just want to know if using the less noisy (or zero noisy) lens will yield same results on both cameras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three of those cameras use the EF-S lens mount, so they should work with pretty much any EF-S lens. If the lens in question has an STM auto-focus motor that is (or is not) noisy, mounting it on a different camera is not likely to change that, since the motor is entirely in-lens - the only role the camera body has is communicating with it via the electronic contacts in the lens-camera interface to tell it what to do.

This might be different if you had a camera with in-body autofocus motor (i.e. some Nikons and other manufacturers), but no Canon EOS model has ever had an in-body autofocus motor.

Comment: Maybe you missed something. Canon 200D's lens makes no noise while focusing. So my question is related to this.

Comment: @VikasKumar Maybe you missed something. Whether or not a lens makes noise while auto-focusing has nothing to do with the camera body. It's all up to the lens and the included auto-focus motor, regardless of which camera body it's currently attached to.

Comment: Maybe you missed something and not trying to realize it. *If the lens in question has an STM auto-focus motor that is noisy* No, it isn't noisy. So will that also work for other cameras without noise?

Comment: The point is that, if it's making noise, it's the lens, not the camera. So, if you attach the same lens to a different camera, it's still going to make the same noise.

Comment: I still don't know why you're not telling this thing in other way :( Is the converse also true? i.e., if the lens in 200D is not making noise, will it also not make noise in 1500D?

Comment: Please reply @twalberg

Comment: @VikasKumar See edit. I don't know how to make it plainer than "If lens A is (or is not) noisy on camera X, then it should (or shouldn't) be noisy on camera Y"

Comment: I also edited my question details. I think I wrote something less in my question.